# Sitemap not working empty page show

Tags: php, sitemap

My sitemap not working its not showing any url or data when i run my sitemap its showing blank empty page

Here is my code for sitemap and  keywords is main table name and check image for my table  [image: structure]

```
        <?php
          require dirname(__FILE__) . ("/includes/includes.php");
         header("Content-Type: text/xml");
        print "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
         $pageLimit = 50000;
      $base = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
       $base = substr($base,0,strrpos($base,"/")+1);
        $link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
       mysql_select_db($db_name,$link); 
        if (isset($_GET["page"]))
         {
print "<urlset xmlns='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd'>";
$page = intval($_GET["page"]);
$from = (($page-1)*$pageLimit);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM keywords LIMIT ".$from.",".$pageLimit;
$result = mysql_unbuffered_query($sql,$link);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  print "<url>";
  print "<loc>".genSearchUrl(implode('-',array_filter(explode('-', str_replace(' ', '-', xmlentities(iconv("utf-8", "utf-8//ignore", $row["keyword"])))))))."</loc>";      
  print "</url>";
}
print "</urlset>";
 }
  else
  {
print "<sitemapindex xmlns='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/siteindex.xsd'>";
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM keywords";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$pages = ceil($row["count"] / $pageLimit);
for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++)
{
  print "<sitemap>";
  $loc = $base."sitemap.php?page=".$i;
  print "<loc>".$web_path."sitemap_".$i.".xml</loc>";
  print "</sitemap>";
}
print "</sitemapindex>";
  }
  exit();
  function xmlentities($text)
 {
$search = array('&','<','>','"','\'');
$replace = array('&amp;','&lt;','&gt;','&quot;','&apos;');
$text = str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
return $text;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? If so you can't output before `header`. `mysql_`usage also could cause the code to break if you are using PHP 7+. You should use PDO or mysqli so this will be compatible with future versions , and you can use parameterized queries. For your current issue check the error log.

Comment: Also you re-invented the wheel, `xmlentities()` is http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

Comment: yes thsi is my actual code so what i need to do here

Comment: Empty page usually means you have errors in your code. You need to have PHP reveal the error to you to debug. I've tried this code with `php -l` and found no syntax error. So it could happen elsewhere or happen on run time. Please add `ini_set('display_errors' 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the top of the PHP code (before `require`) to show the actual error message..

Comment: Step 1: Check the error logs. Step 2: remove the leading spaces before `<?php`.

Comment: here is error logs mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in

Comment: What is your PHP version? Is it error or is it warning?

Comment: yes it is warnning and my php version is 5.6

Comment: there is no spaces in before <?php

Comment: The warning shouldn't matter. Do you have other error message? Also, can you open source code view in your browser to verify that it is actually empty?

Comment: now when i replace all mysql function with mysqli now its showing this only when run sitemap <urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd"/>   and yes browser also showing same like when check in source code

Comment: showing in error log PHP Warning:  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/sitemap.php on line 10
 PHP Warning:  mysql_unbuffered_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in

Comment: I think you should first fix the function calls according to the warnings.

Comment: If you're not sure, search https://php.net for the function documentation to see what parameter are they expecting.

Comment: still no success

Comment: So there is no warning message now? And there is not output in the source code view on browser?

Comment: yes no output on source code only blank message